# F# List.mapi function with filtering

Tags: list, filter, f#

I have a line of code like this:

```
list |> List.mapi (fun i x -> y, i)
```

(Assume that y is already defined type)

But I want to return elements with some condition (e.g filter it)

I am not able to write like this:

```
 list |> List.mapi (fun i x -> if 'condition' then y, i)
```

because it needs else condition as well and I don't have 'else' case.
I also didn't manage to use filter at the same time, because I need to return correct indexes as well, and if I filter the list, indexes will be changed. 
Any ideas?

**EDIT**
By now, I implemented like this:

```
list |> List.mapi (fun i a -> if (a = None) then O, i else X, i) |> List.filter (fun (a,i) -> a = O)
```

I'm giving useless X,i for else case, just to be able to write condition after that and remove X ones. It's working, that's the result I want. But I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you give some more context?  I think it's a bit strange that you have a `list` of `x`s which you are mapping over but don't use `x` at all in the map.  I think, with some more context, there might prove to a better alternative.  For example, if you're trying to associate elements between two lists you might be better off using `zip` than indices.

Comment: I need x in condition, like if x = "someting". Thanks, I will check what zip does

Comment: Is `y` just a fixed value or is it another list/collection that you want to get an element `i` of?

Comment: y is just fixed value, that's why I haven't specified it

Comment: zip is not useful in my case, I'm not combining them

Comment: What are you planning to use `i` to do?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you wish to do. Please provide some sample input and corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me add yet another answer:
From your question and comments I understand that you want to filter a list by a condition depending on the values while retaining the  original indexes.
I'm not sure whether the result should then consist of a list of fixed values and original index or you want to map. The following allows both:

```
let indexedFilterMap p f =
    List.indexed
    >> List.filter (snd >> p)
    >> List.map (fun (i, x) -> f x, i)
```

1. add index
2. filter by p using second values of indexed list, i.e. original values
3. map the remaining values and reverse the order in the tuple (s.t. it is value, index)

If you need the index for the mapping (as the question title includes `mapi`):

```
let indexedFilterMapi p f =
    List.indexed
    >> List.filter (snd >> p)
    >> List.map f
```

Or if you need the index for the filter:

```
let indexedFilteriMap p f =
    List.indexed
    >> List.filter p
    >> List.map (fun (i, x) -> f x, i)
```

The combination should be straightforward.

These can then be used:

```
let list = ['a'; 'b'; 'c']
let condition = (<>) 'b'
let y = "fixed value"

indexedFilterMap condition (fun _ -> y) list // [("fixed value", 0); ("fixed value", 2)]

let m (i, _) = sprintf "fixed value %i" i
indexedFilterMapi condition m list // ["fixed value 0"; "fixed value 2"]

let c (i, _) = i <> 1
indexedFilteriMap c (fun _ -> y) list // [("fixed value", 0); ("fixed value", 2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to filter, but have indexes applied in strictly monotonically increasing order *after* filtering, then filter first, and then add the index values:

```
list |> List.filter condition |> List.mapi (fun i x -> x, i)
```

Here's an example where `b` is filtered away from an alphabetical list of characters:

```
[('a', 0); ('c', 1); ('d', 2); ('e', 3); ('f', 4); ('g', 5); ('h', 6);
 ('i', 7); ('j', 8); ('k', 9); ('l', 10); ('m', 11); ('n', 12); ('o', 13)]
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted it vica verca. index of 'c' should be 2 not 1. Filter should not react on indexes

Comment: And if I mapi first and then filter, I am not able to write condition then, because this condition was already for previous list

Comment: @Kote Why can't you mapi first, and then filter? The `mapi` function in my example above doesn't really *do* anything, so you could easily reverse the expressions...

Comment: Mark, he's not mapping from `x` to `x`, he's mapping from `x` to some fixed value `y`.  To do it with `map` and `filter` you need a `mapi` to get `x` and `i` together, a `filter` for the `x` condition and a final `map` for the `x` to `y` step.  That's why I used `choose` in my answer, because it rolls the final `filter` and `map` into one pass over the list.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be aware that looking up by `i` from a list is an O(n) operation so if that's what you're doing, there could be a more efficient alternative available by expressing the problem differently.

For the problem as described, you could do something like this:

```
list 
|> List.mapi (fun i x -> x, i)
|> List.choose (fun (x,i) -> if 'condition on x' then Some (y,i) else None)
```

Returns a list of tuples of y and an element index that satisfied the condition.

Example:

Consider I start with `['a','b','c','d','e']`, the first `mapi` maps the list to `[('a',0),('b',1),('c',2),('d',3),('e',4)]` then I apply `choose` with (for example) a condition that select vowels and returns some value `y`.  I end up with `[(y,4)]`.

**Edit:**  In response to your update, here is an example of using this in precisely the way you want.

```
list 
|> List.mapi (fun i x -> x, i)
|> List.choose (fun (x,i) -> 
    match x with
    |O -> Some (O, i)
    |X -> None)
```

Comment: This is not what I want, because condition goes only for initial list, afrter maping it, the list is already different and condition is useless

Comment: @Kote No, that's not the case.  Notice that I map to `x` to `x` in the first map so that I can still apply the condition to `x`.  Only in the `choose` do I change `x` to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, if you use sequence expressions you don't need to write the else branch:

```
let list = ['a';'b';'c';'d';'e']
let condition x = x % 2 = 0

[for i = 0 to List.length list - 1 do
    if condition i then yield (i, list.[i])]

// val it : (int * char) list = [(0, 'a'); (2, 'c'); (4, 'e')]
```

But be aware that traversing the list by index is not efficient in a long list. So, it depends what are you looking for, if performance is a must I would use `List.fold` instead:

```
list
    |> List.fold (fun (i, acc) e -> (i + 1, if condition i then (i, e)::acc else acc)) (0, [])
    |> snd
    |> List.rev // if you care about the order
```